# Log concavity of $\int_{x \in \mathcal{C}_1} t^n \, e^{-\sum_i x_i t} \; dx$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a real function $f(x) > 0$ with $n$ strictly positive arguments $x_i>0$ with the following properties:

i) $f(x)$ is homogeneous of degree one in $x$

ii) Strictly increasing in all its arguments $x_i > 0$

iii) Twice differentiable with $\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial \ln x_i}$ (weakly) decreasing in $x_i$ (a weaker property could probably work).

Using this function, let us define the set $\mathcal{C}_t$ for which $f(x)>t$:
$$
\mathcal{C}_t = \left\{ x \; | \; x_i > 0 \; \& \;  f(x)>t \right\}
$$
(If needed, one can further assume that the set $\mathcal{C}_t$ is convex for all $t$)

Then, let us define $G(t)$ as:
$$
G(t) = \int_{x \in \mathcal{C}_t} e^{-\sum_i x_i} \; dx
$$

Note that we can simply use $\mathcal{C}_1$ and write:
$$
G(t) = \int_{x \in \mathcal{C}_1} t^n \, e^{-\sum_i x_i t} \;  dx
$$
since $f(x)$ is homogeneous of degree 1.

Question: Can we show that  $\log G(t)$  is (weakly) concave in $t$?

---

I am trying to solve this problem as part of a longer proof with applications to economics.

It's obvious for the one-dimensional case $n=1$ but I'm already having troubles for $n=2$. But all my simulations support this result. Note: in a limit case where $f(x) = \min_i x_i$, we find that $\ln G(t)$ is linear in $t$.

It would be great if we could show that this is true for any $n$, but the proof for $n=2$ would already be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!